# Call Camel servlet or jetty endpoint in fire-and-forget fashion

Tags: apache-camel

As far as I understand both the servlet and the jetty endpoints in Camel are a Request Reply message exchanges (InOut) expecting an out-message.

Therefore I assume that when I send a HTTP request to those endpoints the response will only be send back once all processors of the route have finished.

Is it possible to call these endpoints in a fire-and-forget fashion, i.e. to just trigger the route and get an immediate response back without waiting for all the processing to be done?

Comment: This question is a basically asking the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981900/camel-how-can-i-send-to-an-endpoint-asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used "seda" to make it async. Note that this only ran async when I used the inOnly-tag:

```
<route autoStartup="true" id="x-service">
     <from uri="servlet:/xService"/>
     <inOnly uri="seda:x-service-execute-async" />
     <transform>
         <constant>OK</constant>
     </transform>
 </route>

 <route autoStartup="true" id="x-service-execute-async">
     <from uri="seda:x-service-execute-async"/>
     ...
 </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, you just need to put some [asynchronous](http://camel.apache.org/async.html) step (EIP or component) in the route...

for example...this route will send all requests to a JMS queue (or seda, etc) which can be processed asynchronously and ACK back to the HTTP client once the message is in the queue...

```
from("http://localhost:9001/inbound")
    .to("activemq:inboundQ");

from("activemq:inboundQ")
    .to(...inbound processing...);
```